# Issue with Variable access in aws airflow

Tags: airflow, mwaa

when I tried to access varaibles in aws managed airflow 2.0.1, got the below exception.

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column variable.description does not exist
LINE 1: ....id AS variable_id, variable.key AS variable_key, variable.d...
```

`vars = Variable.get("some_variable", deserialize_json=True)`

It is working fine with airflow 1.1.0 version, not sure what got changed with 2.0.1

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You probably need to contact mwaa support. description for variables is a feature added on Airflow 2.1 since you are migrating to 2.0.1 the error is very strange.

Comment: thanks Elad, Issue got resolved after recreating the enviorment.